# Code is only showing the last most recent input from temporary array to 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

### Code is only showing the last most recent input from temporary array to 2d array? please help as i'm new to computing and doing it for gcse  (SOVLED)

```
#Prints title
print ("WELCOME TO STUDENT TEST DATABASE")
#array that stores names/scores 
aTestScores =[]

(
"""
  PRESS 1 TO ADD STUDENT AND HIS/HER GRADE
  PRESS 2 TO VIEW STUDENT
  PRESS 3 TO EXIT

"""
   )
SChoise=input("please choose 1 2 or 3"
 #if sChoice == "1":

aT =[]
while True: 
     aT.append (input("Input a name "))
     aT.append (int(input("Input a Test Score ")))  
     print(aT)
     print(aTestScores)
     sPlayAgain=input("Do you want to input another name/number ")
     if sPlayAgain.upper() == "YES":
          continue
     if sPlayAgain.upper() == "NO":
      break 

     print (aT)

aTestScores.append(aT)
print(aTestScores)
```

Comment: IK i changed thx im new to site

Comment: where is `aTestScores` coming from? I'm missing it in your code here

Comment: also what happens if they don't enter YES or NO, you have no case for for that

Comment: Its at the top of my code

Comment: Move `aT = []` outside of the while-loop, the continue statement clears it

Comment: i have a menu in between the aTestScores and this code sorry i didn't include it

Comment: 1 thanks 2 should i do it above or below the while loop it may not mater but what  would u suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redefining aT as an empty list each time the loop repeats. Take the `aT = []` out of the loop and it should work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157674/discussion-on-answer-by-1101110010-code-is-only-showing-the-last-most-recent-inp).