# 2D Array only showing last element in Text function

Tags: java, arrays, processing, nested-loops

My entire code is as follows:

```
package calculator;

import java.util.Arrays;

import processing.core.PApplet;


public class Calculator extends PApplet  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    main("calculator.Calculator");
}

float screenMargin = 40;
float padding = 15;

float w;
float h;

float totalMargin = 2 * screenMargin;

String[][] textToDisplay = new String[][] {
    {
        "1", "2", "3", "*"
    }, {
        "4", "5", "6", "+"
    }, {
        "7", "8", "9", "-"
    }, {
        "±", "0", ".", "="
    }
};
int rows = textToDisplay.length;
int cols = 4;

GridSquare[][] buttons;

public void settings() {
    size(400, 500);
}
public void setup() {

    background(255, 255, 255);
    for (String[] outerArray: textToDisplay) {
        for (String element: outerArray) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(textToDisplay));
}
public void draw() {
    drawCalculator();
    drawButtons();
}

public void drawCalculator() {
    w = (width - totalMargin);
    h = (height - totalMargin);
    rectMode(CORNER);
    fill(125, 125, 125);
    rect(screenMargin, screenMargin, w, h);
    fill(255);
    rect(screenMargin + padding, screenMargin + padding, w - 2 * padding, h / 
8);
}

public void drawButtons()  {
    w = (width - totalMargin);
    h = (height - totalMargin);
    buttons = new GridSquare[rows][cols];
    float margin = 65;
    float calcMarginX;
    float dimensions = 45;
    float totalWidth = margin + dimensions * (cols - 1);
    float idontevencareanymore = 130;
    calcMarginX = w - totalWidth;
    calcMarginX /= 2;
    calcMarginX += screenMargin;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            buttons[i][j] = new GridSquare(i * margin + calcMarginX, j * 
margin + idontevencareanymore, dimensions, dimensions);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < textToDisplay.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < textToDisplay[i].length; j++) {
            buttons[i][j].displayText(textToDisplay);
        }
    }

}

public class GridSquare{

    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float ws;
    public float hs;

    public GridSquare(float tempX, float tempY, float tempW, float tempH)  {   
        x = tempX;
        y = tempY;
        ws = tempW;
        hs = tempH; 
    }

    public boolean onClick(float clickedX, float clickedY)  { 
        return (clickedX > x && clickedX < x + ws && clickedY > y && clickedY < y + hs);
    }

    public void draw() {
        fill(0, 30, 240);
        rectMode(CORNER);
        rect(x, y, ws, hs);

    }

    public void displayText(String[][] text2Display) {
        float squarePadding = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < text2Display.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < text2Display[i].length; j++) {
                this.draw();
                textSize(20);
                fill(255, 255, 255);
                textAlign(CENTER);
                text(text2Display[i][j], x + squarePadding, y + 
squarePadding);
            //  System.out.println(text2Display[i][j]);
            }
        //  text(text2Display[i][0], x + squarePadding, y + squarePadding);
        }

    }
}


}
```

My goal is to make a calculator application in Java using Processing as a library. I am using Eclipse, Processing, and the Proclipsing plugin.

However, when it loops through the 2-D array called `textToDisplay` it only shows the last element for all the elements in the array for one text command.

Why is this happening? (I have scanned my code, and it seems logistically correct. )

What am I doing wrong? (Printing it to the console showed the right code, calling a text function for the array did, as well. I have a feeling it is in the for loop.

How do I fix this?

I looked at similar questions in other languages, but I couldn't find them useful.

[Python Similar Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962722/code-is-only-showing-the-last-most-recent-input-from-temporary-array-to-2d-array)

[C Similar Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881209/last-element-of-2d-array-of-strings-overwriting-previous-array-elements)

[PHP Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773486/foreach-only-showing-last-item-in-array)

Comment: You fill the screen every time in Gridsquare::displaytext

Comment: @Hongyu Wang, can you explain what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nested for loop (2 for loops) around calling the method as *well* as in the method when writing the text. Remove it from inside the method and instead add it as a parameter, and then pass `i` and `j` as a parameter and argument to the method.

Answer (score 2):

In the future, please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting your full program.

The best advice I can give you is to [debug your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). Trace through the code to understand exactly which line is doing something different from what you expected.

You have a few lines like this:

```
rect(x, y, ws, hs);
```

What is the value of `x`, `y`, `ws`, and `hs` when this line executes? Find other similar lines and print out those values as well. Are these values different from what you expected?

If you're still stuck, then I recommend [breaking your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and taking on those steps one at a time. Can you create a simple calculator with just a single button? Now can you add a second button? Get that working before you try to add more buttons.

Then if you're stuck on one of those smaller steps, you can post a more specific technical question along with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck.

Comment: Hi, Kevin, these are the properties of the GridSquare class. I then call many instances of them in a for loop and store these instances in a 2-D Array. I don't think this is the problem. My problem was that it was only displaying "=", the last element in the array. In the future, I _will_ use MCVE, this was the first time I have asked a question on stack overflow, if you check my profile, so I am evidently new to Stack Overflow. I will take your advice and break it down into smaller steps by making a new file with just the parts that are relevant to my problem. Thank you for your advice.